# Смена to mail, а зависимости от input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Есть мультиформа, в ней есть 3 кнопки, которые отправляют свое значение value и input. Можно ли сделать так, что при определенном значении value 1 из 3 менять почту, куда будет уходить письмо?
В общем нужно при `value="1"` отправлять письмо на почту `№1`, при `value="2"` на другую почту ну и при `value="3"` на третью почту.

Сейчас же все письма приходят сюда: `$to = 'test@gmail.com'.',';` ну и на почту , которую ввели в форме.

Обработчик:

```
<?php
// читаем json файл

$json = file_get_contents('../goods.json');
$json = json_decode($json, true);

// письмо

$message = '';
$message .= '<h1>Заказ с сайта</h1>';
$message .= '<p>Имя: '.$_POST['ename'].'</p>';
$message .= '<p>Телефон: '.$_POST['ephone'].'</p>';
$message .= '<p>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>';
$message .= '<p>Выбранная value: '.$_POST['number_apteka'].'</p>';

$cart = $_POST['cart'];
$total = 0;
foreach ($cart as $id => $count) {
    $message .=$json[$id]['name']. ' --- ';
    $message .=$count. ' --- ';
    $message .=$count*$json[$id]['cost'];
    $message .= '<br>';
    $total = $total +$count*$json[$id]['cost'];
}
$message .= 'Всего: '.$total;

//print_r($message);

$to = 'test@gmail.com'.',';
$to .=$_POST['email'];
$spectext = '<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Заказ</title></head><body>';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$m = mail($to, 'Заказ c сайта', $spectext.$message.'</body></html>', $headers);
if ($m) {echo 1;}else {echo 0;}
?>
```

Кнопки:

```
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button next_two" value="Выбрать" onClick="document.getElementById('number_apteka').value = 'Дом 1'"/>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button next_three" value="Выбрать" onClick="document.getElementById('number_apteka').value = 'Дом 2'"/>
<input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button next_four" value="Выбрать" onClick="document.getElementById('number_apteka').value = 'Дом 3'"/>
```

Форма:

```
<div class="email-field form_apteka">
   <div class="input_inline">
        <input type="text" id="ename" placeholder="Ваше имя">
    </div>
    <div class="input_inline">
        <input type="phone" id="ephone" placeholder="+7 ( ___ ) ___ - __ - __" required="" class="input_text tel">
    </div>
    <div class="input_inline">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="e-mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Politics" required=""> <label for="checkbox" class="check_label">Я принимаю условия <a href="#">пользовательского<br>соглашения</a></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="Politics" required=""> <label for="checkbox" class="check_label">Я соглашаюсь с <a href="#">правилами сайта</a></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="number_apteka">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: код покажите Ваш

Comment: добавил, или еще мультиформы код?

Comment: @Ivan [См.пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/79e79c4845f8ea6c0399df5aafe8c7a9112c87d5)

Comment: @Эдуард в вашем методе не разобрался, либо что-то делаю не так

Comment: @Ivan ну что тут можно сказать - разбирайтесь :)

Comment: @Эдуард извиняюсь, видно уже устал)банально, 2 символа пропустил)все работает, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [if/elseif/else](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php) или же [switch](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 0):

Использовать неотфильтрованные пользовательские данные в $message очень небезопасно, каждый POST перед выводом нужно хотя бы обернуть в htmlspecialchars(), а лучше, в дополнение, использовать filter_input().

Пример решения вашей задачи:

```
$emails = [
    'def'   => 'email1@example.com', 
    'admin' => 'email_b@example.com', 
    'seo'   => 'email@example.com',
];
$value = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'value');
if ($value === 'admin') {
   $email = $emails['admin'];
} else if ($value === 'seo') {
   $email = $emails['seo'];
} else {
   $email = $emails['def'];
}
```

Comment: эм.............

Comment: сейчас добавлю более детально, что и как

Comment: Добавил все детали

Comment: В общем попробовал ваш метод, не работает

Comment: Что именно не работает?

Comment: отправка не шла, но воспользовался методом выше и все работает . Ответом от Эдуарда

Comment: @Ivan Вы пробовали адаптировать мой пример к своей задаче? У вас есть переменная $_POST['value'] и в ней может быть значение "admin", "seo"? Вы прочитали на php.net, как работает функция filter_input() и про возвращаемые ей значения? Отправлять почту на $_POST['email'] без её предварительной проверки - хорошая идея? Особенно если эта переменная будет содержать 100500 email: email1@example.com,email2@example.com,email3@example.com,...email100500@example.com?